# T-SQL grouping by changing elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, gaps-and-islands

Hope you are all well and safe!

My first post, I need some help with T-SQL.

How can I flag (to count how many PICK_STATE_CHANGES happened) a list of events from one event to another?

Example, I want to flag (create virtual containers) all rows in the column `oel_class` between 'LABM_PICK_SCAN_LOCATION' and first 'LABM_PICK_DECLARE_TROLLEY_FULL' as 1 and then every next 'LABM_PICK_SCAN_LOCATION' to 'LABM_PICK_DECLARE_TROLLEY_FULL' as previous 1 + 1:

```
user    event_time          oel_class
102480  2020-03-25 12:09:58 LABM_PICK_SCAN_LOCATION <-- this is the starting point of the first virtual container (1)
102480  2020-03-25 12:10:23 TM_TROLLEY_COLLECT -  (1)
102480  2020-03-25 12:12:16 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (1)
102480  2020-03-25 12:12:39 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (1)
102480  2020-03-25 12:13:44 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (1)
102480  2020-03-25 12:14:09 PICK_STATE_CHANGE - etc.
102480  2020-03-25 12:14:39 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:15:20 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:15:20 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:16:17 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:16:51 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:17:27 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:18:02 PICK_STATE_CHANGE
102480  2020-03-25 12:18:02 LABM_PICK_DECLARE_TROLLEY_FULL <-- this is the end of the virtual container
102480  2020-03-25 12:18:48 TM_LOC_CHANGE <-- ignore this
102480  2020-03-25 12:19:28 LABM_PICK_DECLARE_TROLLEY_FULL <-- ignore this
102480  2020-03-25 12:21:40 TM_TROLLEY_PARK <-- ignore this
102480  2020-03-25 12:21:40 LABM_PICK_SELECT_PACK_AREA <-- ignore this
102480  2020-03-25 12:21:48 LABM_PICK_SCAN_LOCATION <-- this is the start of the second virtual container (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:21:55 TM_TROLLEY_COLLECT -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:24:57 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:25:55 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:26:33 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:27:15 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:27:52 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:28:47 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:29:38 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:29:38 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:30:03 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:30:53 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:33:16 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:35:52 PICK_STATE_CHANGE -  (2)
102480  2020-03-25 12:35:52 LABM_PICK_DECLARE_TROLLEY_FULL <-- this is the end of the virtual container
102480  2020-03-25 12:44:05 TM_TROLLEY_PARK <-- ignore this

etc. 3, 4, 5, ...
```

Any ideas? I wanted to do a CASE but how do I say to put a 1 next to specific events following one and then +1 to the 'virtual container'?

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `lead()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select t.*,
    case when oel_class in ('TM_TROLLEY_COLLECT', 'PICK_STATE_CHANGE')
        then sum(case when oel_class = 'TM_TROLLEY_COLLECT' and lead_oel_class = 'PICK_STATE_CHANGE' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by user order by event_time)
    end as grp
from (
    select t.*, 
        lead(oel_class) over(partition by user order by event_time) lead_oel_class
    from mytable t
) t
```